# How to choose the highest number from a set of same names?

Tags: excel

I am trying to modify an already existing Excel file for a client. Here is the deal. They have the following Excel sheet with these columns (the picture is a simplified version of course to make it clear to you):[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU5aY.png)

If a student has completed their Bachelor they get a 1 in the Bachelor Done column, if not they get a 0. Now what they want is to check if at least one person per city has completed their Bachelor and display this in a new table with two columns (First column with the city name and second column with a Note of Yes or No).

For example let's take Lisbon. It has 2 students, George and Helen. In this case George has not completed his bachelor yet (0) but Helen has (1). In that case, Lisbon qualifies and should get a Note of YES in the new table.

Is there any way to implement this in Excel via an IF or a VLOOKUP function? I tried, but my Excel knowledge is quite limited. They also do not want to change the format of the file, as lots of people are already working with this and they are familiar with. Best case scenario could probably be the addition of extra columns.

My question is if there is a way to find for every city the highest Bachelor Done number and based on that to have a Yes or No output. The numbers for Bachelor will always be 1 or 0. So if a city has 1 and 0, 1 should be taken and display yes. If there is a city with 3 people and only zeros, No should be displayed.

If you need any clarification, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First copy and paste all your distinct City names into a column, then remove duplicates (data... remove duplicates). In my case, I did that in column F. Then in column G, input a formula such as this:

```
    =IF(MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,F2) = 1, "YES", "NO")
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you for your very fast and spot on answer, mate. It works exactly as I imagined it. Thank you again, I really appreciate it!